# How to select ip address with prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Im trying to select an IP address using prepared statements with php, if the IP already exist its everything is ok, but if doesnt exist it does never enter inside the `if($stmt -> num_rows === 0)`, it always enter on the `else`like if the query is wrong. The field is setted to `int unsigned`. 
So whats wrong with this `prepared statement?` How can make it enter in the `if($stmt -> num_rows === 0)` when `select` doesnt match anything?

```
$ip_long= ip2long($ip);
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT INET_NTOA(ip), registry_date FROM users WHERE ip = ?');
    if (
        $stmt &&
        $stmt -> bind_param('i', $ip_long) &&
        $stmt -> execute() && 
        $stmt -> store_result() &&
        $stmt -> bind_result($ip, $registry_date_checker) && 
        $stmt -> fetch()
    ) {
       if($stmt -> num_rows === 0) {
          //It does never enter here.
       }
       if($stmt -> num_rows === 1) {
          //If exist enter here.
       }
   }
   else{
       //If select not found anything it always enter here.
       echo "Error mysqli: ".$mysqli-> error; //Returns empty error
       echo "Error stmt : ".$stmt -> error; //Returns empty error
       echo "Numrows: ".$stmt -> num_rows; //Returns 0
       exit;
   }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should check the actual error message and then you would not what went wrong.

Comment: I updated my question. Errors of stmt and mysqli are empty so I suppose nothing is wrong with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mysqli_stmt::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) method returns `null` if no rows exist in the resultset. In the boolean context `null` is interpreted as `false`.

This means if no record is returned by your query, then your first `if` will go straight into the `else` branch.

I would replace `$stmt -> fetch()` with

```
($stmt -> fetch() ?: true)
```

in your first if. This will convert the `null` value into `true`.

Answer (score -2):

You made a typo in your code

Here is it

```
   if($stmt->num_rows() === 0) {
      //It does never enter here.
   }
   elseif($stmt->num_rows() === 1) {
      //If exist enter here.
   }
```

New version of mysqli is using num_rows as function not key object.